# Tracking a button that opens a third-party website

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense, tracking, conversions

I have a dental website for getting appointments. The CTA 'Book an appointment' opens a partner website and the user can see my locations and book an appointment.

Now, to measure Google ads performance, I need to track users coming from Google ads and differentiate them from organic traffic. I have set up the google tag manager, along with the Google Ads conversion tag, and set the trigger on 'Click class'. It's showing the organic traffic in analytics but not coming from ads. I have placed the link with all the UTM parameters in Google ads.

What is wrong here or what is the best possible way to track the clicks on the 'Book appointment' button coming from Google Ads?

Comment: It sounds like you may want a "landing" page and have Google go to that.  It might be difficult to provide more accurate information based on what you have provided - but it seems that the hooks in the partner website to Google are not doing what you need them to - so it may be worth asking the partner what is going on.

Comment: Basically, I just want to track the click event on the button placed on my website, whenever the button is clicked, I just want to get the tracking parameters in my google analytics so that I can measure whether these clicks are coming from Paid campaigns or organic traffic.